# Get all combinations of an array ( if i remove them 1 by 1 )

Tags: c#, .net, linq, theory

Given:

```
{1,2,3}
```

Expected result:

```
{1,2,3},
{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},
{1},{2},{3}
```

So I want basically ALL possible combinations in a list ( but including all possible combinations of - when every element is removed ).

I hope you get what I mean ;)

Question: Which algorithm achieves this?

Comment: Anonymous downvotes, gotta love ’em.

Comment: It's the power set algorithm.

Comment: You may want to read "Introduction to Algorithms", any sophisticated library will have that in stock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) algorithm.

There are some examples on [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set).

Comment: You could at least copy-paste `C#` code from that site ... Otherwise it's more like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Thanks for your comment, I was just about to start writing a **python** recursive function which does this... :D